# Finding a node in a cloned tree using DFS

Tags: c++, tree, depth-first-search

I am trying the LeetCode problem[1379. Find a Corresponding Node of a Binary Tree in a Clone of That Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-a-corresponding-node-of-a-binary-tree-in-a-clone-of-that-tree/):

> Given two binary trees `original` and `cloned` and given a reference to a node `target` in the original tree.
>
> The `cloned` tree is a **copy of** the `original` tree.
>
> Return *a reference to the same node* in the cloned tree.
>
> **Note** that you are **not allowed** to change any of the two trees or the `target` node and the answer **must be** a reference to a node in the `cloned` tree.

This is my code:

```cpp
class Solution {
public: 

    TreeNode* ans = NULL ; 

    TreeNode* getTargetCopy(TreeNode* original, TreeNode* cloned, TreeNode* target) {
       // if(cloned == NULL){return cloned ;}
        if(cloned == NULL){return cloned ;}
        
       // if(cloned->val == target->val){
       //  return cloned ; 
       //  }

        if(cloned->val == target->val){
             ans = cloned ;
        } 
         // return  getTargetCopy(original,cloned->left ,target) ;
         // return  getTargetCopy(original,cloned->right,target) ;  
        getTargetCopy(original,cloned->left ,target) ; 
        getTargetCopy(original,cloned->right,target) ;  
        return ans ; 
    }
};
```

The commented out part was my initial code but it returned wrong answer

Your input

```
[7,4,3,null,null,6,19]
3
```

Output

```
null
```

Expected

```
3
```

Help me understand the problem in my code

Comment: Please provide the code that has the problem. Now it is unclear which commented lines should be there and which not-commented lines should not be there. Just provide one version of the code that has the problem, otherwise it is confusing what you are asking about

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

With these (now commented) lines:

```cpp
    return  getTargetCopy(original,cloned->left ,target) ;
    return  getTargetCopy(original,cloned->right,target) ;
```

...execution would never get to that second line, as the first line would end the function.

These (now commented) lines:

```cpp
    if(cloned->val == target->val){
        return cloned ; 
    }
```

...are fine: once you have found the target value, there is no need to do anything else in this function, and so it is fine to return the node. This is better than setting `ans` to that node and still make some (unnecessary) recursive call(s).

What is missing here is getting the value from the first recursive call, and deciding whether that call successfully found the target value or not. In case it found it, there is no more need for a second recursive call. In case it *didn't* find it, then the second recursive call is needed. Finally, the return value you get from either recursive call, should be returned back as the current function's return value.

So:

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* getTargetCopy(TreeNode* original, TreeNode* cloned, TreeNode* target) {
        if (cloned == nullptr || cloned->val == target->val) {
             return cloned;
        } 
        TreeNode *ans = getTargetCopy(original,cloned->left ,target) ; 
        if (ans != nullptr) {
            return ans;
        }
        return getTargetCopy(original,cloned->right,target) ;  
    }
};
```